# Hottowel app with MySql on Ubuntu with Apache and mono - gets 404 on rest

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, ubuntu, mono

Is it possible to host johnpapas hottowel application (https://github.com/johnpapa/HotTowel-Angular) on Ubuntu, running Apache and with mono?

More information about my application:

- .Net framework 4.5
- REST-api
- MySQL

Right now I can access the website and html, css and javascript seems to work, but I cant access the REST-api that is specified in Controllers, for example:

```
public class CustomersController : ApiController
{
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/customers")]
public List<CustomerDto> GetAll()
{
  CustomerssService customersService = new CustomersService();
  var list = customersService.GetAll();
  return list;
}
}
```

When trying to access them I get 404, for example:

```
Request URL: http://server/application/api/customers/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
```

PS. Everything works fine when running local on my Windows with IIS Express.

Thankful for all advices!